# Custom ListView: separator entries ignore settings

Tags: android, listview, custom-controls, list-separator

I've created a custom ListView with separators (using [this](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) tutorial). It looks and works fine but the separators are still clickable, focusable and able to get a context menu called from. So i've tryied to "shut them up":

```
...
case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
    convertView.setFocusable(false);
    convertView.setClickable(false);
    convertView.setLongClickable(false);
    break;
        }

return convertView;
```

But they totally ignore these settings! For testing purposes i used `covertView.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA)` and it works well. Anyone got an idea what could be wrong?

Comment: are you using `lstView.setOnItemclickListener()`

Comment: Of course I do, this is not the problem! All of entries within the list can be clicked, what i need is to restrict the separators responding to clicking and long-clicking.

Comment: you can `setOnClickListener();` to the `convertView` inside `getView()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your adapter is one that implements BaseAdapter (such as an ArrayAdapter), override the [isEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#isEnabled%28int%29) method in the adapter.

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    if (getItemViewType(postion) == TYPE_SEPARATOR) {  // method taken from example
        return false;
    }
    return super.isEnabled(position);
}
```

To keep track of which items are separators and which are not, keep an ArrayList or some other type of collection that keeps track.

Comment: I updated the code to use a method specified in the tutorial.